# Display site language setting in source code

Tags: plugins, language

I manage a plugin.  I have people often complain about translations and have found that sometimes they don't have their site set to their local language.

Is it possible in site source code to display the site language as chosen in `Settings > General` ?

e.g. I have a comment `<!-- plugin version 123 -->`.  Is it possible to display `<!-- plugin version 123 (Fr) -->` if the language is French?

Comment: There's [`get_locale()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_locale/) and `get_bloginfo( 'language' )`, if that helps.

Comment: A proper theme should have an accurate `<html lang="">` attribute set with `language_attributes()`. See in [`_s`](https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/master/header.php#L14). So with that in place you can always have the set language in the opening `<html>` tag.

Comment: @SallyCJ would you like to put that as an answer for me to accept?  get_bloginfo( 'language' ) did exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to display `<!-- plugin version 123 (Fr) -->` if the
>   language is French?

Yes, it is possible and you can use [`get_bloginfo( 'language' )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/) which returns a language tag like `en-US` for `English (US)`.

So if you just want to retrieve the first 2-or-3 character code (e.g. `en` for `en-US` and `en-UK`) of the language tag, you can do:

```php
list ( $lang ) = explode( '-', get_bloginfo( 'language' ) );
echo '<!-- plugin version 123 (' . ucfirst( $lang ) . ') -->';
```